# How to deselect checkboxes using a button in python?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I need to have a button which clears selected check boxes. Please anyone guide me. Thanks in advance.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import*

top = Tkinter.Tk()
CheckVar1=IntVar()
CheckVar2=IntVar()

C1=Checkbutton(top, text = "Music", variable = CheckVar1,
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5,
                 width = 20,activebackground="red",bg="green")
C2=Checkbutton(top, text = "Video", variable = CheckVar2,
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5,
                 width = 20)

C1.pack()
C2.pack()

B = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello",activebackground="red",
    ,bd=3,bg="green",width=5) #Button

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you tried simply setting the associated variable to zero?

Comment: Yes but It didn't work..

Comment: It works for me with the code posted in your question. I added a function that calls `CheckVar1.set0)` and `CheckVar2.set(0)`, and it works just fine. When you say it doesn't work for you, please show exactly how you're doing it, and any error that you get.

Comment: What I want is to clear off the marked checkboxes in the window. I have added the following code. But it does not get cleared when I click on the button. I am using pyDev for this. Maybe something wrong with my API ?

Comment: What "following code" are you talking about? Please edit  your question to include _exactly_  the code you've tried with the code in your question.

Comment: def clear():
    CheckVar1.set(0)
    CheckVar2.set(0)

Comment: _please edit your question_. That code should work. Please show us an _actual_, _fully working_ example. Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 13):

Create a function that will set the value of CheckVar1 and CheckVar2 to 0.

```
def clear():
    CheckVar1.set(0)
    CheckVar2.set(0)
```

And then just link it with the button.

```
B = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello",activebackground="red",
bd=3,bg="green",width=5, command = clear) #Button
```

BTW, you had an extra comma here.